# Play streaming videos on firefox with html5 or flash

Tags: html, flash, firefox, video-streaming

I am trying to stream video file on web. my server is httpd 2.2 runnin gon centos 5 64 bit. So far it has worked well with ie9, chrome, opera but I have issues with firefox. I cannot rely on a user to have certain plugins installed. I want the video to be able to play in html5 if not supported then roll onto flash. The following is the current code that I have.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="modernizr.custom.13466.js"></SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function supports_canvas() {
      return !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext;
    }

function supports_video() {
    console.log("supports video");
    console.log(document.createElement('video').canPlayType);
      return !!document.createElement('video').canPlayType;
    }

function supports_h264_baseline_video() {
      if (!supports_video()) { return false; }
      var v = document.createElement("video");
      return v.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"');
    }


function supports_ogg_theora_video() {
      if (!supports_video()) { return false; }
      var v = document.createElement("video");
      return v.canPlayType('video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"');
    }

function supports_webm_video() {
      if (!supports_video()) { return false; }
      var v = document.createElement("video");
      return v.canPlayType('video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"');
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    /*console.log("document ready");
    if ( !supports_video() ) { 
        console.log("false");   
        return false; 
    }
*/

    if (Modernizr.canvas) {
          // let's draw some shapes!
        } else {
          // no native canvas support available :(
        }
});
</script>

    <!-- first try HTML5 playback: if serving as XML, expand `controls` to `controls="controls"` and autoplay likewise -->
    <!-- warning: playback does not work on iOS3 if you include the poster attribute! fixed in iOS4.0 -->
    <video width="640" height="360" controls>
        <!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <!-- Safari / iOS video    
        <source src="movie.ogv" type="video/ogg" />-->
        <!-- Firefox / Opera / Chrome10 -->
        <!-- fallback to Flash: -->
        <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            data="movie.swf">
            <!-- Firefox uses the `data` attribute above, IE/Safari uses the param below -->
            <param name="movie" value="movie.swf" />
            <param name="flashvars"
                value="controlbar=over&amp;image=movie.jpg&amp;file=movie.mp4" />
            <!-- fallback image. note the title field below, put the title of the video there -->
            <img src="movie.jpg" width="640" height="360" alt="__TITLE__"
                title="No video playback capabilities" />
        </object>
    </video>
    <!-- you *must* offer a download link as they may be able to play the file locally. customise this bit all you want 
    <p>
        <strong>Download Video:</strong> Closed Format: <a
            href="movie.mp4">"MP4"</a> Open Format: <a href="movie.ogv">"Ogg"</a>
    </p>-->

</body>
</html>
```

I have placed the following in .htaccess file and httpd conf

```
AddType video/mp4 mp4
AddType video/ogg ogg
AddType video/webm webm
```

I have also loaded the following into httpd

```
AddHandler h264-streaming.extensions .mp4
LoadModule h264_streaming_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_h264_streaming.so
```

Message in firefox i get is: *firefox no video with supported format*

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support MP4. If a browser supports HTML5 video, it will look for a file it can play. If it can't find one, it does not then fall back to the Flash version automatically, so for Firefox (and Opera - which also doesn't support MP4), you'll need to also provide a WebM format (and Ogg if you want to support Firefox 3.6).

Comment: does my code not fall back to flash player, if not how can I achieve this? I have followed this guide http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody

Comment: No, if a browser supports HTML5 video, then it will only try to use that. The Flash fallback is only for a browser that doesn't support HTML5 video, such as Internet Explorer 8 and below. The only way you could achieve this is to write JavaScript that detects whether the browser supports video and playing MP4, and to use Flash if not. Alternatively, use one of the many libraries out there such as MediaElement.js (http://mediaelementjs.com/) to do it for you.