# Firefox does not find Flash Player Plugin on Centos / Linux

Tags: linux, flash, firefox

In our production environment we are installing a Web-based product. The Operating System is Centos 6.5.  For this product, we have installed Firefox-33 and Flash Player 11.2.202.406-release.x86_64.  The problem is that Firefox starts, but it does not detect Flash Player Plugin.

The following error message is reported when we run Firefox:

1411663263429   addons.manager  ERROR   Exception calling provider startup: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [mozIGeckoMediaPluginService.addPluginDirectory]"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/OpenH264Provider.jsm :: OpenH264Provider.startup :: line 271"  data: no] Stack trace: OpenH264Provider.startup()@resource://gre/modules/addons/OpenH264Provider.jsm:271 < AMI_callProviders()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:875 < AMI_startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:750 < AMP_startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:2322 < AMC_observe()@resource://gre/components/addonManager.js:55 <

Questions are:

1. Why is Firefox not detecting or connecting to Flash Player Plugin?
2. Is Gecko Media Plugin not functioning, or not able to detect Flash Player?
3. What steps should we take so that Firefox can detect the Flash Player Plugin ?

We would really appreciate any help in this regard.  In case this is not the right (sub)-forum, please advise where we should post this question.

Our past searches found some links like below, which did not help or cover this specific query:

[Flash Player Does not Show up on Firefox but not Chromium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447297/flash-player-does-not-show-up-on-firefox-but-not-chromium)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=firefox+on+centos+flash+plugin+

http://www.niharsworld.com/2012/06/15/solved-adobe-flash-player-plugin-working-firefox-13-white-screen-visible-video/

[Play streaming videos on firefox with html5 or flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800544/play-streaming-videos-on-firefox-with-html5-or-flash)

Answer (score 3):

Please try following step to get Flash player in your Cent Os.

FOR 32-bit x86

```
rpm -ivh http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/adobe-release/adobe-release-i386-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-adobe-linux
```

FOR 64-bit x86_64

```
rpm -ivh http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/adobe-release/adobe-release-x86_64-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-adobe-linux

yum check-update


yum install flash-plugin nspluginwrapper alsa-plugins-pulseaudio libcurl
```

Comment: If you already have Flash on CentOS and only need to update it, this worked: **sudo yum upgrade flash-plugin**

Answer (score 1):

Fellow Developers and Users,

Thank you Altmish for sharing your insights into how to fix the problem detailed above.  After reviewing your comments, and doing extensive research, the following process solved our problem.  We are sharing it in the spirit of helping others out.

**After RPM download, close all firefox make sure no processes of firefox are running.**

```
rpm -aq | grep flash-plugin

rpm -e or (-ev –force) flash-plugin-[version details]
```

**Also, from your home directory**

```
rm -rf ~/.macromedia/

rm –rf /usr/lib(or lib64)/mozilla/
```

**Enable the adobe 32bit repository**

```
yum install flash-plugin

yum install nspluginwrapper

cd /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins-wrapped

rm *libflashplayer.so

ln -s /usr/lib(or lib64)/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so
```

**Open Firefox and it works.**

Comment: If you want to respond to another user's answer, please leave a *comment* underneath the answer. If you feel that your question needs more context, you should *edit* the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to get this working. (Centos 7)

1. Upgraded to the latest Firefox version (33.0.3) at the time of this writing. Just download the latest *.bz2 package, extract it and create a soft link to `/usr/bin/firefox`
2. Downloaded the latest flash version. Extract this. Copy `libflashplayer.so` to the Firefox directory.

Installing Firefox (Close Firefox first)

```
tar -xvfj firefox-33.0.3.tar.bz2
mv firefox /opt/
cd /opt/firefox
ln -sf /opt/firefox/firefox-bin /usr/bin/firefox
```

Installing Flash

```
tar -xvf install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz 
cp libflashplayer.so /opt/firefox/
```

**Adjust the versions accordingly (use tab)**.

Answer (score 0):

below link works for me on centos 7 and Mozilla Firefox 38.0.1

[install flash-plugin in centos](http://tecadmin.net/install-adobe-flash-player-on-centos-redhat-fedora/)

hope this will work too for you.

i answered because any one else struggling with the same issue could find it working..